# C#: How to pass parameter key/values to a function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that takes in a bool, shown below:

```
public void LoadEndPoints(bool mock)
{

}
```

I can call this via LoadEndpoints(true) or LoadEndpoints(false), but this can be a bit hard to understand, as you need to know what true/false represents. Is there a way to pass the parameter name and value to a function such as LoadEndPoints(mock = true)?

Comment: You should comment your code to make that clear. You should use XML comments, which will be represented in the intellisense to ensure you and future developers will understand.

Comment: I don't understand why using "named parameters" would help here.. and there are so many answers relating to such.

Comment: Perhaps: 1) Use discrete method names: `LoadEndPoints/LoadMockedEndPoints` or; 2) Take in a enumeration (or other type) that conveys more meaning: `LoadEndPoints(EndpointMode.MockOnly)` or; 3) Move the configuration to a [class-level] setting: `var epl = new EndPointLoader { Mock = true }; epl.LoadEndPoints()`; etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree, your code should be more readable.

Comment: I wouldn't call this code "non-readable" although there might be better ways to express the high-level end goal. *The method-level documentation should explain the `mock` parameter.* Perhaps the name could be expanded (e.g. `mockOnly`), but otherwise I think it's generally "ok". There are *many* methods that take `bool` types and it's up to the caller to know how to call the method correctly.

Comment: Side note, how come you are using a variable for mocking? In what context is variable `mock` used, in testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!**

You can specify the parameter names like this:

```
myObject.LoadEndPoints(mock: true);
```

**Further Reading**

- [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Another way to improve readability of your code would be to use an enum, like this:

```
public enum LoadOption
{
    Normal,
    Mock
}

public void LoadEndPoints(LoadOption option)
{
    ...
}
```

Then the call would look a bit like this:

```
myObject.LoadEndPoints(LoadOption.Mock);
```

Comment: @MustafaEkici OP specifically asked know how to make the code more readable by specifying the parameter name as well instead of just the parameter. The way I read the question this is *exactly* what OP is asking for. That said, *aquaraga*'s answer is good too.

Comment: @MustafaEkici What do you mean? I've showed how it can be done and linked to detailed references. *aquaraga*'s answer listed the same solution.

Comment: its different not same.. check your refrence example, there is weight and height right? they are already defined. so think that i call that method with parameter 30 (parameter means Age or can be everything) so how you get that name (Age) in the function?

Comment: @MustafaEkici and what would a parameter named 'age' do? Why would you expect to be able to pass any parameter with any name to any function that doesn't define what that parameter is or does? I'm sorry, but I fail to see why that would be a criticism of this technique.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 'Named arguments', a C# 4.0 feature; and thus call: `myObject.LoadEndPoints(mock : true);`

If readability is indeed your prime concern, you could even expose two explicit methods, and internally reuse the logic - something similar to:

```
    public void LoadEndPointsWithoutMock()
    {
        LoadEndPoints(false);
    }
    public void LoadEndPointsByMocking()
    {
        LoadEndPoints(true);
    }
    private void LoadEndPoints(bool mock)
    {

    }
```

Also, I wouldn't say that `LoadEndPointsWithoutMock`, etc. are great method names. Ideally, the names should have something to do with the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a KeyValuePair:

```
   KeyValuePair kvp = new KeyValuePair(BoolType, BoolValue)
```

Comment: What would a call to the method look like, using `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: The other answers are better, but LoadEndpoints would take a KeyValuePair instead of a bool

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with the following syntax in c#:

```
myObject.LoadEndPoints(mock : true);
```

And in VB:

```
myObject.LoadEndPoints(mock := true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use named parameters. Have a look at this [Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)